# UPDATE Table based on the same table with relations to other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 2 tables:

```
Product (Id, RefKey, ParentId)
example data.: (1, 'SX1234', NULL), (2, 'SX4321', NULL)
```

and

```
ProductSTAGE (Id, RefKeyCode, ParentCode)
example data: (1, 'SX1234', 'SX4321')
```

where Product.RefKey = ProductSTAGE.RefKeyCode

How can I update Product table based on these relations to result

```
Product (Id, RefKey, ParentId)
result data.: (1, 'SX1234', 2)
```

I used

```
    WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT P.ParentId FROM Product AS P
)
UPDATE CTE SET ParentId = P2.Id
FROM Product AS P2
INNER JOIN ProductSTAGE AS PS ON PS.RefKeyCode = P2.RefKey
WHERE PS.ParentCode IS NOT NULL
```

but using this my Product.ParentId always is equal Product.Id

Comment: Using an `UPDATE` statement with a `JOIN`. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: because the data in ProductSTAGE table come from external source

Answer (score 0):

I found my CTE problem but CTE is not necessary on this issue. This query works and should be enough for me:

```
UPDATE P
SET P.ParentId = P2.Id
FROM Product AS P
INNER JOIN ProductSTAGE AS PS ON P.RefKey = PS.RefKeyCode
INNER JOIN Product AS P2 ON P2.RefKey = PS.ParentCode
WHERE PS.ParentCode IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: `WHERE PS.ParentCode IS NOT NULL` is not necessary because of the `= PS.ParentCode` in the join